# Russian Keyboard and English keyboard?

Tags: узус

My Question just came across my mind.

If I use the keyboard I have here and if there is a Russian keyboard...do they go the same as a translate between English and Russian ?

Comment: The English and Russian layouts are different, [have a look](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/KB_Eng-Rus_QWERTY(%D0%99%D0%A6%D0%A3%D0%9A%D0%95%D0%9D).svg/450px-KB_Eng-Rus_QWERTY(%D0%99%D0%A6%D0%A3%D0%9A%D0%95%D0%9D).svg.png).

Comment: The link you provide me doesn't work... try again. thanks

Comment: Hmm... OK, here's another link: http://www.lingvoda.ru/images/kb_common.gif

Comment: That's better but should it be more than that ? I'd like to have similiar to it but in PDF so I can take a look at it ?

Comment: Look, it's a site about Russian and not about keyboards and creating PDF. Can't you just google "Russian keyboard layout"?

Answer (score 3):

Though it is not quite clear to me what do you mean by "go the same as a translate", I'll try to answer.

There are no special "Russian keyboard", all keyboards in Russia are just standard keyboards with Russian layout printed on key caps. But they do not differ in drivers, embedded software or anything else.

To be able to type Cyrillic letters, you need to add an appropriate layout to your system. There are many Cyrillic layouts, mostly we use "ЙЦУКЕН" (named by left part of the firs row), but you can use a phonetic one, where Cyrillic letters are put on keys with similarly sounding Latin letters.

You can also look at the [article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B) on Wikipedia about Russian layouts, but it's only available in Russian. You can take a look at pictures with layouts though. And there is a bit of information about Russian layouts in [English article on layouts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Russian).